# How can you replace entire state in Redux Toolkit reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immer.js

EDIT: The solution is to return `state` after I replace it completely (`return state = {...action.payload}`)!  But why?  I don't need to return it when I replace the fields individually.

I'm working with the [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/), which simplifies some Redux boilerplate.  One thing they do is use Immer to allow you to directly 'modify' state (in fact, you're not).  It works fine, except I don't know how to replace my section of state entirely.  For instance, I want to do something like this

```
const reducer = createReducer({ s: '', blip: [] }, {

    [postsBogus.type]: (state, action) => {
        state = { ...action.payload };
    }
```

but `state` remains untouched.  Instead I have to do this

```
[postsBogus.type]: (state, action) => {
    state.s = action.payload.s;
    state.blip = action.payload.blip;
}
```

Is there a way I can replace state entirely?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, as you noted, you must return a new value to replace the state entirely.

Even in a "plain" Redux reducer, assigning `state = newValue` does nothing, because all that does is say that the *local function variable* named `state` is now pointing to a different value in memory.  That does nothing to *return* a new value.

For Immer specifically, [you can either mutate the *contents* of the Proxy-wrapped `state` value as long as it's an object or array, or you can return an entirely new value, but not both at once](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/return).

Comment: I also ran into this trouble. Even after reading Immer's docs, I thought that doing `state = getInitialState()` from a slice reducer was safe, since it "feels" like I'm returning (or the slice will be implicitly returning) a new `state` value without doing any mutations to it (cause the mutations are implicitly done inside the new state value). I think this could be more clear in the docs. In regular Redux, I was always using `return` on every `switch-case` anyway, so this wasn't a problem (even when I was using Immer's `produce`).

Comment: This link is now dead, and I don't see anything to replace it in the immer docs. Is there no longer a supported way to do this?

Comment: Immer appears to have updated their docs structure to drop the `/docs/` portion from the URLs as part of a switch to Docusaurus v2, and that's broken their external links. Just replaced the Immer docs link in this post with the correct URL.

Comment: Ran into this problem as well; the solution this helped with is `return {...action.payload}`

Comment: @MaximP, you don't need the destructuring, just `return action.payload` is sufficient, as per the docs.

Answer (score 7):

You can, but not in this way, when you say:

```
function x(y){
   y = 4
}
```

You're mutating the function parameter, but not the state of redux,
you have two options to update this state of your redux store:

either to set `state.your_state_name = something` or, in your case, what you want to do is to **return** a new object, the new object is what the new state value is going to be.

simple example:

```
myReducerFunc: (state, action) => {
  return {...action.payload }
},
```

another example:

```
const loggedInUserSlice = createSlice({
  name: '$loggedInUser',
  initialState: {
    isLoggedIn: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    loggedIn: (state, action) => {
      return {
        isLoggedIn: true,
        ...action.payload,
      }
    },
  },
})
```